# DAX how to do SUMMARIZECOLUMNS() and only return where =COUNT>2

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to write a dax function where I can achieve the below visual in a measure. I actually need to get the count of it:

[image: visual]

as you can see, I need to group by transcation date, registeration and quantity, and then select * where count(quantity) > 1.

I couldn't go further than this:

```
number of issues on same day = = 
COUNTROWS(FILTER(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Transaction'[Transaction 
Date],'Transaction'[REGISTRATION],"CountQuantity",[Number of 
Ref (CM)]),[Number of Ref (CM)] > 2))
```

the visual shows the whole record but I need to show the count of such info as a measure in a card. so it will show 1 in my count for the below card. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we have a measure and we need to use it as part of filter then use a variable.

```
TestCard = calculate (countrows('Table'), Filter(ALL('Table'), var __count = [CountMeasure] return __count>2 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself:

```
=COUNTROWS(FILTER(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Transaction'[Transaction 
    Date],'Transaction'[REGISTRATION],"CountQuantity",[Number of Ref (CM)]), 
    [Number of Ref (CM)] > 1))
```